# TInyMCE - protecting against broken HTML being pasted in?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

If someone grabs something off a page or email and doesn't capture everything, then pastes that into TinyMCE with missing tags (like `<p>` and `<div>`), how do you protect against those un-closed tags spilling into the rest of your page?   Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into implementing the [Tiny MCE Paste plugin](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin%3apaste), it has an option `paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste`you can set to true to tidy any HTML once it's pasted in.

From the linked example:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    theme : "advanced",
    mode : "textareas",
    plugins : "paste",
    theme_advanced_buttons3_add : "pastetext,pasteword,selectall",
    paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste : true,
    paste_preprocess : function(pl, o) {
        // Content string containing the HTML from the clipboard
        alert(o.content);
        o.content = "-: CLEANED :-\n" + o.content;
    },
    paste_postprocess : function(pl, o) {
        // Content DOM node containing the DOM structure of the clipboard
        alert(o.node.innerHTML);
        o.node.innerHTML = o.node.innerHTML + "\n-: CLEANED :-";
    }
});
```